# How to initialize a Binding : Bool variable in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, init

How to initialize `shouldPopToRootView`? Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DoctorHomePage: View {

    @Binding var shouldPopToRootView : Bool

    init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
               Text("Hello, World!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this out:

```
struct DoctorHomePage: View {

    @Binding var shouldPopToRootView : Bool

    init(shouldPopToRootView: Binding<Bool>) {

        self._shouldPopToRootView = shouldPopToRootView
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    } // I get the error here

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, World!")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        DoctorHomePage(shouldPopToRootView: .constant(true))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris: Can you explain the necessity of that *underscore* thing in front of the variable name? So why it is "self._myVar" and not just "self.myVar"? I lost almost 2 hours to find that underscore trick, wenn I encountered multiple init-problems with a binding in a custom initializer for a struct.